# Building List of JSON Objects in Ansible

Tags: ansible, json

I'm trying to build an array/list of JSON objects in Ansible.  My playbook is called by specifying `--extra-vars "userids=123456,654321"`.

I then try to build the list with the following.  "TBD" is just a place-holder.  I will fill those values with data retrieved from SQL queries later in the playbook.

```
- name: Initiate User List
      set_fact:
        all_users: []    

    - name: Add new JSON Objects to List
      set_fact:
        all_users: "{{ all_users+ [{ 'UserID': '{{ item }}', 'UserType': 'TBD', 'UserName': 'TBD' }] }}"
      loop: "{{ userids.split(',') }}"

    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: all_users
```

The list sort of builds, but it is skipping the first item in the list.  This is the resulting output:

```
TASK [Initiate User List] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Add new JSON Objects to List] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=123456)
ok: [localhost] => (item=654321)

TASK [Debug] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all_users": [
        {
            "UserID": "654321",
            "UserType": "TBD",
            "UserName": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "UserID": "{{ item }}",
            "UserType": "TBD",
            "UserName": "TBD"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I tried doing a "set_fact" before the looping task to perform the split() first, but that didn't help.  I also tried "with_items" instead of loop, no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use nested curly braces `"{{ ... {{ item }} ... }}"`. Correct syntax is

```yaml
all_users: "{{ all_users+ [{ 'UserID': item,
                             'UserType': 'TBD',
                             'UserName': 'TBD' }] }}"
```

Next, it's more convenient to submit a list of `userids`. Then the `split` filter is not necessary. For example the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Initiate User List
      set_fact:
        all_users: []
    - name: Add new JSON Objects to List
      set_fact:
        all_users: "{{ all_users +
                       [{ 'UserID': item,
                          'UserType': 'TBD',
                          'UserName': 'TBD' }] }}"
      loop: "{{ userids }}"
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: all_users
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "userids=['123456','654321']" playbook.yml
...
    "all_users": [
        {
            "UserID": "123456",
            "UserName": "TBD",
            "UserType": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "UserID": "654321",
            "UserName": "TBD",
            "UserType": "TBD"
        }
    ]
```

---

Remove the single-quotes from the items in the list `userids` if the attribute `UserID` shall be stored as `integer` type instead of `string`. For example

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "userids=[123456,654321]" playbook.yml
```

gives (there are no quotes around the values of `UserID`)

```yaml
    "all_users": [
        {
            "UserID": 123456,
            "UserName": "TBD",
            "UserType": "TBD"
        },
        {
            "UserID": 654321,
            "UserName": "TBD",
            "UserType": "TBD"
        }
    ]
```

---

Then use a dictionary to create the list of users. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_users:
      123456:
        name: Alice Admin
        type: admin
      654321:
        name: Bob Business
        type: sales
  tasks:
    - name: Initiate User List
      set_fact:
        all_users: []
    - name: Add new JSON Objects to List
      set_fact:
        all_users: "{{ all_users +
                       [{ 'UserID': item,
                          'UserType': my_users[item].type,
                          'UserName': my_users[item].name }] }}"
      loop: "{{ userids }}"
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        var: all_users
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e "userids=[123456,654321]" playbook.yml
...
    "all_users": [
        {
            "UserID": 123456,
            "UserName": "Alice Admin",
            "UserType": "admin"
        },
        {
            "UserID": 654321,
            "UserName": "Bob Business",
            "UserType": "sales"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks! removig the extra {{ }} as well as the single quotes around 'item' did the trick. I had removed the {{ }} at one point, but didn't remove the single quotes, so the result just had "item" for both userIDs.

Comment: OMG, man! BIG Thanks!!!